# Filter all values except a specific set, remove duplicates, remove another specific value then join the result in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, filtering, google-sheets-formula

Trying to join together neatly unique specific values which are randomly generated while excluding duplicates and ignoring a specific value I already have.

[image: Sample]

The result of the selected cell in the picture above should be "Melee Or Ranged Or SPEL".  This should be drawn from the "Affixes" section above, and ignores the value below "Base Scaling Type," while excluding all other values

This should be achieved ideally without the addition of extra rows, columns or values.

From various posts I've tried formulas like:

```
=iferror(join(" Or ",(Filter(Unique(E8:J8),E8:J8<>L10,E8:J8<>"",E8:J8="Melee",E8:J8="SPEL",E8:J8="Ranged")),L10),L10)
```

However, their issues were specifically removing duplicates or specifically filtering a value, and I couldn't find one where they combined both into one formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR ", TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(E7:J8)), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 contains 'Scaling'", 0), NOT(COUNTIF(L10, 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(E7:J8)), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 contains 'Scaling'", 0))))))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=JOIN(" OR ", UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E8:J8, NOT(COUNTIF(L10, E8:J8))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks this answered the question perfectly... However since i was tired and frustrated I forgot to include a critical point in my question and have rewritten it: 

more than just the values "Melee", "Ranged" and "SPEL" can occur in the Affix section, I would also like the formula to exclude all values except these three while achieving the same result.

Bonus points if you can also re-add the single excluded value to the start of the result.

Sorry, and thanks for your time ^^

Comment: @FIRE so what **exactly** should be in L10?

Comment: L10 contains the base scaling type of the weapon.  This is also random, but is always one value from "Melee", "Ranged" or "SPEL"

Comment: To clarify some more, this is a random generator for weapons.  They can have random properties assigned to them called "Affixes" one of which adds another kind of "Scaling" to the weapon which your character could use instead of its base scaling type, assuming it didn't roll the same type.  So the goal here is to check the affixes and what its base scaling type is, and list which of the three the weapon can now use.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thanks for dealing with my weirdly specific question so patiently :)

Comment: Done.  One one minor issue though, for some reason the Unique function wasn't working, however if you move it to infront of the Transpose function it starts working... for some reason.  Will update the answer with the edited function.